# Check if line is same with another line in a file

Tags: python

I want to check in a file, it will check all the lines, if a line same with any other line; code will say "line number B is same with line number A."

```
------- lines.txt ----------
1 | first line
2 | this line
3 | i am another line
4 | this line
-------------------------
> Alert: Line 4 is same with line 2!
```

- If possible but not important, please make it faster.
- If possible, can we check every 5 lines like it will check only line 5, 10, 15, 20...
- The line numbers does not exist in the real file. They are only for showing the line number.

Comment: Faster than what?

Comment: I mean this will be tried on lots of lines like 100 K or 1 M. So it needs to be as fast as possible i don't know a way but maybe you know.

Comment: Have you tried anything? On Stackoverflow you are expected to show at least some effort on solving the problem on your own

Comment: I know you are right but I am new to Python and searched somethings with np module but not successful at all just tried and failed too many times.

Comment: What does the tag qr-code have to do with this at all?

Comment: LOL ,my project was about it . Removing thanks for saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this and it should work:

```
with open('lines.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

for i1,l1 in enumerate(lines):
    for i2,l2 in enumerate(lines[i1+1:]):
        
        if l1 == l2:
            print(f"Alert: Line {i1+1} is the same with line {i1+i2+2}!")
```

Comment: Oh, it looks you understood my line numbers wrong. They were just for showing the line numbers they does not exists at start of the lines. If you can you can edit so others can see but I will try to edit myself first. Thanks